# copy iPhone simulator to clipboard not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, photoshop

I am trying to copy the iPhone simulator to use in photoshop for a website.  I want to create a static image from one of my apps pages with the iPhone casing.

When I try to go to the simulator menu and select edit-copy screen, the screen contents are copied and can be pasted in photoshop.

However when I select edit - copy, for some reason the entire simulator including the bevel is not copied to the clipboard or perhaps copied in a format that is not recognized.  The clipboard remains empty.

I can do a screen shot and then do some work in photoshop to remove everything beyond the boundary but just wondering if anyone has figured out a way to copy the simulator including the bevel to the clipboard for use in other apps.

Just wondering why the edit - copy is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the normal macOS screenshot shortcuts for that: press  <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> to start the screenshot-to-clipboard and then press <kbd>Space</kbd> to change to the window selection. Move the mouse over the simulator window (which turns blue) and press the mouse/touch pad button. This copies the window including its shadow (but without any background). Use <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> to save to a file on the desktop instead.

You may need to enable the shortcuts: open the system preferences, go to *Keyboard* > *Shortcuts* > *Screen Shots*.

Comment: that's excellent.  thanks very much.  only one minor issue.  the label that says the iPhone model and iOS (iPhone X - 11.3 for example) under the phone obscures the shadow.  Is there anyway to not show this label?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. Might be worth posting another question for that.